# Error locating div aria label with xpath Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I'm trying to find a way to make sure my bot doesn't get confused and click on the **Following** button again (it uses span to detect text) when it has already followed that particular user. I am trying to detect that if a user is already followed, the bot should skip him through another method, which is if the bot finds the following text on the user's profile **"Turn on Tweet notifications"** that means the user is already followed because there will be a **bell** icon/button present on his profile.

The issue is, I fail to detect that text/button. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
def to_follow_delay():
    def to_follow_delay_2():
        try:
            driver.get(next(urls))
            if wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label,'Turn on Tweet notifications')]"))):
                i = 1
                while True:
                    skipped_user = "skipped_following" + str(i) + ".png"
                    if not os.path.isfile(skipped_user):
                        break
                    i += 1

                already_following = datetime.datetime.now()
                print(already_following, "Already following... skipping")
                driver.get_screenshot_as_file(skipped_user)

                def skip_user():
                    driver.get(next(urls))
            
                skiptimer = threading.Timer(10, skip_user)
                skiptimer.start
                return to_follow_delay()
            else:
                def follow_user():
                    sleep(5)
                
                    followuser = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Follow"]')))
                    followuser.click()
                
                    followsuccess = datetime.datetime.now()
                    print(followsuccess, "Follow successful")

                    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - starting4))

                    i = 1
                    while True:
                        followed_user_success = "followed" + str(i) + ".png"
                        if not os.path.isfile(followed_user_success):
                            break
                        i += 1
                        
                    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(followed_user_success)

                    followedper_runcounter.set(followedper_runcounter.get() + 1)
                    followedcounter.set(followedcounter.get() + 1)
                    return operation_follow()

                timer4 = threading.Timer(tofollowdelayvalue_txt.get(), follow_user)
                timer4.start()
                starting4 = time.time()

        except StopIteration:
            nourls = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(nourls, "No more urls.")
            return

    timer5 = threading.Timer(5, to_follow_delay_2)
    timer5.start()
```

Twitter code:

```
<div aria-label="Turn on Tweet notifications" role="button" tabindex="0" class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1niwhzg r-1ets6dv r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-6gpygo r-1kb76zh r-2yi16 r-1qi8awa r-1ny4l3l r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr"><div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1awozwy r-18jsvk2 r-6koalj r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-b88u0q r-1777fci r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-q4m81j r-qvutc0"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-18jsvk2 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-z80fyv r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr r-19wmn03"><g><path d="M23.24 3.26h-2.425V.832c0-.414-.336-.75-.75-.75s-.75.336-.75.75V3.26H16.89c-.414 0-.75.335-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h2.426v2.424c0 .414.336.75.75.75s.75-.336.75-.75V4.76h2.425c.415 0 .75-.337.75-.75s-.336-.75-.75-.75zm-6.23 7.606c.02-2.434-.782-4.597-2.258-6.09-1.324-1.342-3.116-2.084-5.046-2.093h-.013c-1.93.01-3.722.75-5.046 2.092C3.172 6.27 2.37 8.433 2.39 10.867 2.426 15 .467 16.56.39 16.62c-.26.193-.367.53-.266.838.102.308.39.515.712.515h4.716c.11 2.226 1.94 4.007 4.194 4.007s4.083-1.78 4.194-4.007h4.625c.32 0 .604-.206.707-.51s0-.643-.255-.838c-.082-.064-2.043-1.625-2.008-5.76zM9.745 20.48c-1.426 0-2.586-1.11-2.694-2.508h5.388c-.108 1.4-1.268 2.507-2.694 2.507zm-7.29-4.007c.702-1.095 1.457-2.904 1.434-5.618-.017-2.062.614-3.8 1.825-5.025C6.757 4.774 8.172 4.19 9.7 4.184c1.527.007 2.943.59 3.985 1.646 1.21 1.226 1.84 2.963 1.823 5.025-.022 2.714.732 4.523 1.437 5.618H2.455z"></path></g></svg><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r-poiln3 r-a023e6 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"></span></div></div>
```

The error stacktrace:

```
    if wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Turn on Tweet notifications'][role='button']"))):
  File "C:\Users\Cassano\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF6903+2517251]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A8F8E1+2095329]
        Ordinal0 [0x00992848+1058888]
        Ordinal0 [0x009BD448+1233992]
        Ordinal0 [0x009BD63B+1234491]
        Ordinal0 [0x009E7812+1406994]
        Ordinal0 [0x009D650A+1336586]
        Ordinal0 [0x009E5BBF+1399743]
        Ordinal0 [0x009D639B+1336219]
        Ordinal0 [0x009B27A7+1189799]
        Ordinal0 [0x009B3609+1193481]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00C85904+1577972]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D30B97+2279047]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B86D09+534521]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B85DB9+530601]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A94FF9+2117625]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A998A8+2136232]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A999E2+2136546]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AA3541+2176321]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x770EFA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B47A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B47A6E+238]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To locate the *visible* element with text as ***Turn on Tweet notifications*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Turn on Tweet notifications'][role='button']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Turn on Tweet notifications' and @role='button']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Doesn't locate the element. Gives me Timeout Exception...

Comment: Update the question with complete error stacktrace

Comment: Updated it! Check now.

Comment: I am not sure if this is right so my apologies, but are you there? Just making sure that you saw I updated the post.

Comment: @Cassano Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: Sure, I'd love to do that!